# How to set Mod_Env in Apache24 Windows

Tags: python, apache, apache2, apache2.4, mod-env

Maybe a silly question, but how do I pass environment variables in apache. I have enabled the `LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so` statement in apache's `httpd.conf` file and I know from [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html) that I should use the statement `PassEnv env-variable [env-variable]`. But where exactly do I need to add this line (in which file and on what position)?

I.e. I want my system variable

```
PassEnv PYTHONPATH C:\Python\DLLs;C:\Python\lib;C:\Python;C:\Python\lib\site-packages
```

to be propagated to my web-server. Where do I put it?

Sorry, I'm an absolute beginner with apache and can't seem to find any step-by-step instructions for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the environment variable in a [`.htaccess`](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/) file, which needs to be placed in the root of your website:

```
PassEnv PYTHONPATH C:/Python/DLLs;C:/Python/lib;C:/Python;C:/Python/lib/site-packages
```

Notice that I use forwards slashes in the path so that apache won't interpret them as escape characters.

To enable the use of `.htaccess` files you also need to make sure so the webroot (in other words the `DocumentRoot`) has `AllowOverride All` in the configuration:

```
<Directory "C:/WEBROOT">
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I have created a EnvVar.htaccess file with the comand line from above and placed it to the website root (C:\Apache24\htdocs\Test).
However it seems to have no effect...when I call my pythonscript python.py (C:\Apache24\htdocs\Test\cgi-bin) which simply executes: `print("PYTHONPATH" in os.environ)` I get `False` as an output. Am I missing something?

Comment: The filename should be `.htaccess` not `EnvVar.htaccess`. To be sure that the path will get correctly parsed by apache I should also use forward slashes i.e `PassEnv PYTHONPATH C:/Python\DLLs;C:/Python/lib;C:/Python;C:/Python/lib/site-packages`

Comment: Did the changes, restarted apache and even physically restarted the pc but still no effect. Could it be a permission problem?

Comment: You can try to check the log files - I don't know where it might be located on windows, but you should be able to check using something like `apache2ctl -S` or `httpd -S` I think

Comment: @N.Maks - I updated my answer. If you need more help I could guide you through it in the chat instead

Comment: I created a chat for this topic: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151874/windows-apache24-setenv

Comment: Thank you Cyclonecode for your support! I acctually managed to find a workaround, by setting `os.environ['PYTHONPATH']='C:/Python/lib/site-pa‌​ckages'` within the python script itself and it seems to propagate it when being called via a web request.